# Renaming duplicates in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, update

I have a table with a few columns (id, col2, col3, geom) in a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database.
I want to find all duplicates (or more) from "col3" having that they share value in "col2". 
The next step would be to rename those duplicates (or more) to something unique (anything will do).

As a first step I've managed to get the records that are duplicates (or more) from my table with this statement:

```
SELECT col2, col3,  Count(col3) from my_schema.my_table  
group by col2, col3  
having Count(col3)>1;
```

However this does not give me the “id” column that tells what records to rename.  Any ideas on how to include the id-column and still be able to achieve what i described above? Is there a way to rename the records that are duplicates so that all records are unique in “col3” when “col2” is unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, run the duplicate check while updating via `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE <table> AS t1
  SET col3 = t1.id::VARCHAR || '_' || t1.col3
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM <table> AS t2
    WHERE t1.id <> t2.id
      AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
      AND t1.col3 = t2.col3
  )
RETURNING *;
```

This will change `col3` into a composite value (`<id>_<col3>`), similar to @JGHs answer and with `col3` being changed into `VARCHAR` prior to updating, for each row where a duplicate combination of `col2 AND col3` exists in the table.

The `RETURNING *` will list all rows that have been changed.

IME `EXISTS` is ultimate in performance (when applied correctly), and it's failsafe for a case like this.

---

Sidenote:

I can't make up a usecase, and you might just have a good reason for this; still I can't really see the benefit here...

I suppose your `id` is unique, and if you don't care for the `col3` content, or have it combined *with the id*, the column is obsolete in my eyes.

If there is a reason to keep all those columns, the reason might just imply that there *are* duplicates, and you might be better off to add a column and populate it with a 'ranked' sub-id, by partitioned windows just like in @JGHs `rn` generation. Or, of course, with the composite value as above. Or with an array of ids from actual duplicates...

Comment: I hade to change datatype to varchar in a separate clause before your executing the statement, for some reason, but apart from that your solution seem to work perfectly. Appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't really care about `col3` content, the easiest way would be to update the entire table, maybe replacing its content by a sequence output.

If it does matter and you want to keep the value for cases when `col2,col3` doesn't have any duplicate, you can make use of a window function.

Basically, you would write a sub query that partitions the data by `col2,col3`. Then, for each combination, you compute the row number. The sub-query returns all original rows and columns (well, the ones you need, including `ID`) and this new computed field.

At last, you update the original table by joining the subquery results by `ID`, and you restrict the update when there are at least a duplicate, and you can concatenate (using `||`) the row number (`rn`) to the `col3` value to make it unique:

```sql
UPDATE t set col3 = gp_t.col3 || gp_t.rn 
FROM  
(
    SELECT row_number() over (partition by col2,col3 order by id) AS rn, 
    id,
    col3
    FROM t
) AS gp_t
WHERE t.id = gp_t.id
and rn>1;
```

Comment: After changing datatype on "col3" from bigint to char, your code worked fine, thanks.  However, when I run my code from above I still get 65 records that have duplicates (better than 1770, but still). Any ideas why this can be? Could it be a result of the rownumber building new values in "col3", making new duplicates?

Comment: @Abbe it could be the existing values... but since you didn't gave any hint about existing values, I can't comment much. You can choose a different aggregation such as `col3 || '-' || rn` or `col3 * rn ` etc.

Comment: I will try another aggregation too, appreciate your help.